# Mover un <li> al final del Navbar Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, bootstrap

Este es un nav general entregado por bootstrap 5. Estoy tratando de llevar el Dropdown al final del NavBar y que Home y Link se mantengan en su posicion original.

He probado con float-end, flex, margenes, pero no logro hacer que solo ese en especificio se mueva.

El codigo original del navbar d bootstrap 5

```html
        <>
   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li> <hr class="dropdown-divider"/></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        
      </ul>
     
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

        </>
```

Comment: Tienes que entender que como el dropdown esta dentro de una lista (ul ), se mostrara junto a los demás elemento (li), puedes optar por: 1 sacar el dropdown de la lista y de esta forma poder posicionar lo sin afectar los demás elemento, 2 crear una clase y asignar un posicionamiento absoluto o usar la pseudo-clase :last-child

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ver si te sirve esta solución.
En esencia lo que hace está alineado por defecto a la izquierda (al start), luego haces que ocupe todo el ancho disponible (**clase w-100**).
Ahora haces que el item justo antes del drop down crezca y ocupe todo el espacio posible con la clase **flex-fill**
Puedes [verla funcionando aquí](https://creatuweb.espaciolatino.com/sols/dropdown_derecha.htm#)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent" style="">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 w-100">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item flex-fill">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li> <hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        
      </ul>
     
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```